# Problems selecting a div depending on text inside

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

i've been working on a project with puppeteer and it was going great so far until a tried to localize div's depending on their text.
I can't use the div id, name or class, i need to find it by the text inside of it.
My idea is to create an array of all the text i need to find and then loop trought the div's to find the ones that match any of the text in the array.
Can anybody help me find a solution? Thank you!

Comment: do you use jquery? if yes then have a look here https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: No, i'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward using vanilla javascript (no JS libraries):

```
// Get an array of all <divs>:
let allDivs = [... document.getElementsByTagName('div')];


// Loop through allDivs, checking the text of each one:
allDivs.forEach((div) => {

  let textInsideDiv = div.textContent;

  // THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
  // if (myArrayOfText.indexOf(textInsideDiv) > -1)) { etc.}
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, i have a question though, "let textInsideDiv = div.textContent" on that part, hoy am i suppose to indicate wich text i have to find in the div?

Comment: That;s the `indexOf` line, commented out, towards the bottom. Translated into English, `if (myArrayOfText.indexOf(textInsideDiv) > -1)` means `If the textInsideDiv matches any of the elements inside myArrayOfText`.

Comment: Oh, ok, that explains it, i'll try that and i'll tell you how it goes, thank you!